# Graphics card not working even with the latest drivers?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, ati-mobility-radeon

I have a new laptop **Acer Travelmate P-255 MG** which had linpus Linux on it, and has a graphics card:

- Name: AMD Radeon 8750M
- Vendor ID: 1002
- Devicde ID: 6600

I installed Windows 7 x64 on it, and I got all the drivers from Acer support website, but after installing the AMD driver I still see the **Standard VGA Adapter** in the device manager with another listing showing **AMD Radeon 8750** but with a yellow triangle, when I double click on it I get this message:

> Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times, I also got the lastest driver from amd.com without resolving the issue.

So how can I find what's the problem ? and how can I check if I have hardware problems or software problems ?

Comment: Are you downloading the drivers released by and or acer?

Comment: Interesting issue - can I assume when you had Linux on it, there was no issue? And I'm not being rude, but are you downloading the 64bit version (if there is one)

Comment: @Ramhound I tried both drivers, the version on the amd website is newer that's the only difference.

Comment: @DaveRook I had linpus linux without any GUI, and I didn't use it much so I don't know if it was working before, I have have a Debian Live USB with Gnome 3, I'll try it when I get home and post back, but how can I check from Debian if it's working fine ?

Comment: We need to know additional details from the installation log

Comment: @DaveRook yes I'm downloading the 64bit version from this [link](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Windows+7+-+64)

Comment: Peter, fine about the link, just checking as I think we've all downloaded (I have many times) the incorrect file before as it's an easy mistake :) ... Out of curiosity, did you try the Beta?

Comment: @DaveRook yeah I know you're right, also on the Acer website they only have the 64bit drivers, how we're supposed to know the problem if the error message is not helping at all "**reported problems (code 43)**" ? I'll try the Beta and see what I get.

Comment: Peter, I'm guessing you could even try an older driver, but as you probably know, code 43 is useless really, it's too generic and so debugging is really hard. At the moment, I'd consider the card is faulty, but, and don't laugh, there is a MS fixit for this issue http://support.microsoft.com/mats/hardware_device_problems/

Comment: @DaveRook I tried everything and when I installed the driver of the second device everything worked fine, check out my answer for the details, and thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the question in the device manager there are 2 devices:

- AMD Radeon 8750M
- Standard VGA Graphics Adapter (which is an Intel card, with the standard driver that comes with windows 7)

I was checking the BIOS, where I had 2 options for **Graphics Mode**:

- Switchable (default)
- Integrated

When I set it to integrated it disables the AMD card and the laptop uses the Intel card alone, so I searched about it and it seems that the laptop has 2 graphics controllers one of them which is the Intel controller is used for low power usage while the other one which is the AMD controller is used for games or any other applications that require high graphics performance, so the computer switches between them depending on the applications and if the power is plugged in.

So when I installed the driver for the Intel controller, the yellow triangle on the AMD device was removed and everything worked fine, so maybe it was reporting a problem because  it needed the driver of the Intel controller because they're meant to work together.